# Trouble with a sub menu in my WordPress menu

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, submenu

I'm creating my first WordPress theme. It's a very simple one for a friend's website, who is a music producer. I'm creating the navigation menu. One of the items on the menu is listen. It's not an actual link. You hover over it and a submenu should appear. So I made Listen a custom link.

The problem is that the submenu doesn't appear. The Submenu has its own class. But I don't think WordPress is reading the CSS

Here is the CSS:

```
ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: -20px;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
display: block;
text-align: left;
background-color: grey;
}

ul.sub-menu li:hover {
background-color: #dae0e6;
}

ul.main_nav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
}
```

Here is the HTML and php code in the header.php:

```
<nav>

<?php   

$defaults = array(
    'container' => false,
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class'    => 'main_nav'   
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
<!--
<ul class="main_nav">
    <li>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a>Listen</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="musicOriginal.html">Originals</a></li>
            <li><a href="musicTvfilm.html">TV/Film</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a href="credits.html">Credits</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
-->
</nav>
```

Comment: no one can help you like this you should put the link of your site to see it directly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's a good first post, you discovered how to mark down code.  I have removed the last statement, a plea/thanks adds nothing to the question.  Others need to see what you observe with your current code.  Please either put a link to your website or post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

I changed css so its shows menu sub menu with CSS.

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/agrxzxn6/3/)**

```css
nav
{
 margin-top:15px
}

nav ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

nav ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

nav ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

nav ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

nav ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

nav ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

nav ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

nav ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul class="main_nav">
     <li>
         <a href="home.html">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
     </li>
     <li> 
         <a>Listen</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="musicOriginal.html">Originals</a></li>
             <li><a href="musicTvfilm.html">TV/Film</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>   
     <li><a href="credits.html">Credits</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In example above your menu is commented out. Also parent of ul.sub-menu should be positioned relative.

Answer (score 0):

since you are new ... I think you should start by get general idea about the sub menu and style them in WordPress .

this Tut will help you 
http://wproots.com/how-to-style-wordpress-menus-dropdowns/

also I will suggest other option for you .

1. start form other theme like wordpress deafult theme and edit it
2. start form starter theme like `http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/`
3. start from template

its hard to build theme from scratch if you are new ... step by step

Answer (score 0):

**please assign width to ul like**

```
ul.sub-menu {
 display: none;
}
```

and plaece

```
ul.main_nav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:800px;
}
```

just after it